# How to remove all from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need google map to have only street names. I wan't to remove things like marked buss stations, hospitals etc. 
What command can I use to remove this things?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can style the base map as described here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html

For example, to hide everything but roads:

```
var styleArray = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "road",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "on" }
    ]
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styleArray});
```

The full list of features that can be styled is here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

You may want to turn `parks` back on, for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can used the Styled Maps in v3 of the Google Maps API to remove items on the map you don't want.

Try it out here on the Styled Maps Wizard

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only can use 4 types of [maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#BasicMapTypes), Satellite, Hybrid, Terrain and Roadmap. I recommend you to use the roapmap, it is the simplest map it has the street names and by default it doesn't has anything else, like the transit overlay.

In other words you can't remove just some items from the maps, you only can add new layers of your own data.

**UPDATE:**

Look at @Mike Jeffrey answer

Comment: But ROADMAP type still has elements like busses, ships, schools etc. :(

Comment: You can used Styled Maps to remove things like bus icons or other POIs. Try it here http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html